# Cant download 15,000 files via ssh linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, ftp

I have used wget, ncftp ftp etc, They all list around 5000 files at some sort of limit. I tryed using wget to get an exclusive file that didnt show up in the regular wget download and it worked. I know the files are there it just wont download all of them. help ASAP!!

Answer (score 1):

use rsync, it uses ssh and can handle a very large amount of files.

Comment: I get 
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(605) [sender=3.0.9]

Comment: can you post the rsync command you are using?

Comment: rsync -av -e ssh user@host:/from/ /to

Comment: There is a password to it, I can connect to it using ncftp and ftp.

Comment: but not via filezilla

Comment: Can you post link to reference stating this limitation doesn't exist in rsync?

Comment: Rsync cannot work over ftp.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried downloading it recursively using `wget --mirror`?

PS

If this is a FTP server only (or HTTP and FTP only) rsync won't work: it's a different protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Try using secure copy (`scp`) with the recursive flag (`-r`).