# How to download large amounts of files via ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, download

I am trying to download around 15,000 individual user files from an FTP backup space. I know the files exist because if I put a certain username that was not downloaded with the regular wget it can be downloaded.

I have tried ncftp and ftp

Comment: Can you explain this part? "if I put a certain username that was not downloaded with the regular wget it can be downloaded". It might be clear to you but I have no idea what you mean with it.

Comment: I ment a certain filename.

Comment: wget gets the filenames to download from the HTML structure. If there is no index.html (or similar) to feed the names to wget then you either need to give it a list (e.g. with a text file and the -i option) or use a FTP client and use the mget and prompt commands.

Comment: can i have an exsample?

Comment: What is it today with people needing to download 15,000 files one of which is not retrieved by wget? http://superuser.com/questions/578790/cant-download-15-000-files-via-ssh-linux

Comment: it only downloads about 5000 of the files, (they are userfiles for a server i run) say somebodys name was  Zen i can download Zens user file directly, but if i use -r it only gets to around D

Comment: Maybe the server limits the number of files it will send for a single request?

Comment: Good point. In that case the OP will need to split the requests. Since @legit already has the index.html file it might be able to use wget with the -i option.

Comment: the index file only has about 5000 of the files inside it.

Comment: Why not try to wget only a subset of the files with each request, but issue multiple requests? Say [a-c]*, then [d-f]*, then [g-i]*, lather, rinse, repeat.

Comment: Please clarify if you have any way of actually logging on to a normal shell on the remote machine. Can you `ssh`? Can you run commands on the remote server in anyway other than FTP?

Answer (score 0):

FTP example as requested (can't put it in a comment and keep the formatting)

```
user@mycomputer:/home/somedir> ftp
ftp> Open storage.provider.tld
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
220 storage.provider.tld FTP server (Version 6.00LS) ready.
name: YourUSERNAME
331 Password required for YourUSERNAME
Password: TypeYourPassword
230 User YourUSERNAME logged in.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.

ftp> prompt
Interactive mode off.

ftp> mget *
local: test remote: test
229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||60396|)
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for 'test' (10 bytes).
100% |*************************************|    10     184.25 KB/s    00:00 ETA
226 Transfer complete.
10 bytes received in 00:00 (34.75 KB/s)
local: test.iso remote: test.iso
229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||64833|)
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for 'test.iso' (0 bytes).
     0       0.00 KB/s
226 Transfer complete.
local: test.uue remote: test.uue
229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||50714|)
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for 'test.uue' (0 bytes).
     0       0.00 KB/s
226 Transfer complete.
(etc etc for all files)
```

Without the `prompt` command you would need to confirm all files. Not the best idea when there is 15000 of them.

Also, my client started in binary mode (`Using binary mode to transfer files.`). If yours starts in ASCII mode then type `bin`.

you can get subsets. E.g. all files starting with an a (`mget a*`) or cd into folders (`cd` to change dirs on the FTP computer, `!cd` to change dirs on your local computer. It just cd to it before you start ftp).

Comment: That just got index.html

Comment: it also doesnt get every file. it limits it to around 5000 again.

Comment: maybe if there was a way to zip it across ssh?

Comment: If there is just a signel file (index.html) than it is not FTP based but web based. What is in the index.html? Just <HTML><head></head><body>Welcome!</body></HTML>, or are there filenames in there. IN that case `wget -r http://storage.provider.tld`. Or use it to construct a file and use the `--input-file=file` from wget.

Comment: As to 'zip over SSH'. 1) If you can log in via ssh, you can either tar it locally and ftp or wget the single file (`tar cf my_archive.tar *`) or you can use netcat.

Comment: it was the filenames inside the index

Comment: i cant login to the server, i can only login with the other server, maybe if i got a desktop and putty on the linux server i could.